# Adding a Third Table to a Two-Table Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

The query below works just fine.  It pulls fields from two MySQL tables, "comment" and "login".  It does this for rows where "username" in the table "login" equals the variable "$profile."  It also pulls fields for rows where "loginid" in the table "comment" equals the "loginid" that is also being pulled from "login."

I would like to pull data from a third table called "submission," which has the following fields:

```
submissionid loginid title url displayurl datesubmitted
```

I would like to pull fields from rows in "submission" where "loginid" equals the "loginid" that is already being pulled from the other two tables, "login" and "comment."

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

Query:

```
  $sqlStrc = "SELECT l.username, l.loginid, c.loginid, c.commentid, c.submissionid, c.comment, c.datecommented
               FROM comment AS c
         INNER JOIN login AS l
                 ON c.loginid = l.loginid
              WHERE l.username = '$profile'
           ORDER BY c.datecommented DESC
              LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: I see you found much of my answer on your duplicate question useful but no upvote! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853318/join-with-three-tables

Comment: Hi Dave... I appreciate your help, but it didn't get me very far on my last question.  What I'm posting here is what I was using before I posted that last question.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT l.username,l.loginid,c.loginid,c.commentid,c.submissionid,c.comment,
c.datecommented,s.submissionid,s.loginid,s.title,s.url,s.displayurl,s.datesubmitted

FROM comment AS c

INNER JOIN login AS l ON c.loginid = l.loginid
INNER JOIN submission AS s ON s.loginid = l.loginid

WHERE l.username = '$profile'

ORDER BY c.datecommented DESC

LIMIT 10
```